# Split Latitude and Longitude - but extra comma

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataset that has latitude and longitude listed as follows under the column name location_1:

,     (34.0545, -118.2499)

I don't have much of an issue removing the parenthesis and moving them into separate columns under normal circumstances, but I absolutely cannot figure out how to make it work while also dropping the first comma before the numbers.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be good to have few more rows in the example. Also include the code that you already have to remove the parenthesis and moving them into separate columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `tidyr::extract` with the following regex.

```
tidyr::extract(df, location_1, c('lat', 'lon'), 
                  regex = ',?\\s*\\((\\d+\\.\\d+).*(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)\\)')
```

Comment: Just gave it a shot, but it did not work. There is no difference in the dataset (no new columns, or anything). Odd.

Comment: @bcongelio I don't know how your data looks like. Add data using `dput`, See here on how to give a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Answer (score 0):

I find this an intuitive way for me:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(location_1 = '(34.0545, -118.2499)')


df %>% 
  mutate(location_1 = str_sub(location_1, 2,-2)) %>% 
  separate(location_1, into = c('lat', 'long'), sep = ',')
#>       lat       long
#> 1 34.0545  -118.2499
```

in the column *location_1* of your *df* the first and last sign is striped off. Then the string is split at `,` into *long* and *lat*.

Comment: after re-reading your post and having a closer look I recognized the comma before the paran. If the data looks like `',(34.0545, -118.2499)'` you can use `str_sub(location_1, 3,-2)`.